# convert array layout while removing duplicate values

Tags: javascript

I need to take serviceType from my array and convert it to the following layout keeping only the unique values.

[
{
"Label": "Cars Now"
"Value": "Cars Now"
},
{
"Label": "Vans Now"
"Value": "Vans Now"
},
]

I've got the unique values below, but I can't work out how to convert it to the layout I need.

```js
const inputArray = [
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "4x4"
},
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "web",
"wheelType": "2x4"
},
,
{
"serviceType": "Vans Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "2x4"
}
]

let tempArr = inputArray.map(row => row.serviceType) // map extracts the serviceType
           .filter(service => service); // filter removes any undefined/empty values

newServiceSet = [...new Set(tempArr)] // only keeps unique values

console.log(newServiceSet)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the Set of `serviceType`s into an an array of strings, then map to turn each string into an object. You also need to filter out the empty space in the array.

```js
const inputArray = [
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "4x4"
},
{
"serviceType": "Cars Now",
"applictionType": "web",
"wheelType": "2x4"
},
,
{
"serviceType": "Vans Now",
"applictionType": "Direct",
"wheelType": "2x4"
}
];
const serviceTypes = new Set(inputArray.filter(Boolean).map(({ serviceType }) => serviceType));
const output = [...serviceTypes].map(label => ({ label, value: label }));
console.log(output);
```